# Show Euclidean plane with usual topology is not compact

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I need to show an open cover with no finite subcover.

**My try**

I assume Euclidean plane with usual topology deals with open sets/intervals.
So

Let A=(a,b). Let $G_n$:=(a-(1/n),b) for each
n$\in $N then A =$\bigcup_{r=1}^{\infty}G_n$. So
G is an open cover for A
. Let {$G_{n_1},G_{n_2}$,…,$G_{n_k}$ } be
a subcollection of $G_n$ .Take
K=max{$n_1,n_2$,…,$n_k$ }
then $\bigcup_{r=1}^{K}$ $G_{n_r}$= $G_n$ =(a-($1$/K),b)

Since $a-(1$\K)$\in$ A$\notin$ $G_K$ ,no finite subcover can be found.

Therefore A is not compact.

I hope I solved it.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: This argument successfully shows that an open interval on a line is not compact. This is not the same as showing the whole Euclidean plane is not compact. For this you need to display an open cover of the whole plane with no finite subcover

Comment: Ok, so I have to use disks say $B_r$($0$) as a cover of E. Take a sub collection {$B_{r_0}(0),…,B_{r_k}(0)$} The union of subballs is the original ball.,so no finite subcover exists?

Comment: That's basically it. I'm not sure what you mean by "the original ball.". You need to cover the whole Euclidean space by, for example,  the collection of balls $B_r(0)$ where $r=1,2,3,.....$. This clearly has no finite subcover.

Comment: I did that .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a family of open sets $$U_n =\{(-n,n): n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

$$\mathbb{R}=\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(-n,n)$$

But this open cover has no finite subcover.

Comment: I used this prove R is not compact...Thanks